# Second Person To Resign

Tags: sentence-structure

I have a question about sentences on the web similar to the following.

> 1. John is the second person to resign from the company ***after Mike***.
> 2. John is the second person ***after Mike*** to resign from the company.

I am trying to analyze the above sentences.  Sentence 1 is a short version, I think, of this:

> 1a. John is the second person to resign from the company ***after Mike did***.

But when I tried to use the same method to analyze sentence 2, I got this strange sentence:

> 2a. John is the second person ***after Mike did*** to resign from the company.

Did I do something wrong in my analysis of sentence 2?  Or, is it that sentence 2 is not even standard English, and therefore should not be analyzed in the same way as sentence 1?

Comment: Why do you think you need to add "did" in there? Why not "resigned"?

Comment: I take it you do realize that regardless of where you position ***after Mike***, and regardless of whether you include ***did*** or not, most native speakers would *probably* assume you meant only two people resigned (Mike, followed by John). But it's perfectly credible (and perhaps even more "logical") to read it as meaning John is *the second of two people who resigned after Mike himself resigned*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So, sentence 2 is poorly written?  And therefore, sentence 2a is not relevant?

Comment: @ColleenV So, sentence 2 is poorly written? And therefore, the rewrite sentence 2a is not relevant?

Comment: So, you're not going to answer my question?

Comment: @ColleenV  Wouldn't adding a second "*resigned*" be too wordy?

Comment: Wordy, shmordie, meatie. You're trying to analyze it, not rephrase it for publication.

Comment: Are we playing a [game of questions](https://youtu.be/fGEYFE7e_R8)?

Comment: @TRomano Rosencrantz & Guildenstern are Dead is one of my favorite movies. Every time I re-watch it, I catch some allusion I missed.

Answer (score 2):

Consider these legitimate variants:

> After Mike, John is the second person to resign.
>
> John is the second person to resign, after Mike.
>
> John, after Mike, is the second person to resign.
>
> John is, after Mike, the second person to resign.
>
> John is the second person, after Mike, to resign.

Minus the adverbial, **after Mike**, the sentence reads:

**John is the second person to resign.**

The idiomatic meaning of **second** here is absolute, not relative. John is the second, not Mike's ordinal position + 2.

Syntactically, **after Mike** would modify the predicate  "John *is* {} ".

**John is, after Mike...**

On the semantic level, the adverbial "after Mike" + "the second" express the idea that Mike has already done the thing mentioned in the main clause, namely, *resigned*.

**After** has a temporal meaning that coincides on the semantic level with the ordinal, **second**.

Comment: So, the "*after*" in sentence 1 (in my original post) should be interpreted differently than the "*after*" in sentence 2a (original post)?

Comment: @meatie: Your 2a is ungrammatical. "is the second person after Mike did "

Comment: But "John is the second person to resign after Mike *resigned*." could mean that there was another resignee between John and Mike. But it would be ambiguous. If you wanted to state it unambiguously: After Mike and Joe, John is the third person to resign. or ... "*Since* Mike resigned, there have been two more resignations."